# Windows 7 / 64 bit: How to change File Extensions of all file within a folder

Tags: windows-7

I have several hundreds .jpg Images. The problem is, that some have ".jpg" and others have ".JPG" as the file-extension.

I'm on Windows 7, 64 bit. How can I easily change all file-extensions to the same name (".jpg" in this case)? Is there some kind of commandline-command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from a command prompt in the directory: `ren *.* *.jpg`

Comment: Or to be more specific: `ren *.jpg *.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

To do it recursively:

```
for /r %f in (*.jpg) do rename "%f" "%~nf.jpg"
```

or

```
for /r %f in (*.jpg) do rename "%f" "*.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

A powershell way:

```
get-childitem | where {$_.name -match 'JPG'} | %{rename-item -path $_ -newname "$($_.basename).jpg"}
```

**Edit: Requested explanation**

The get-childitem is much like the old 'dir' command.

where is actually an alias for where-object and is a filtering cmdlet

The percent sign (%) is an alias for the cmdlet foreach-object, which performs a for loop for each item that it is passed.

rename-item is pretty self explanatory. :)

The $_ you see is a special symbol for "THIS." "THIS" is whatever object it is working on at the time.

So in plain English:

**"Get the files in the current folder that contain 'JPG.' For each of those, rename them with the original base name, and add '.jpg' to the end."**

update: Stumbled across [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822745/rename-files-to-lowercase-in-powershell) on stackoverflow. Looks like it would fit the bill.

Comment: Can you explain what this command does in some detail?

Comment: Updated just for you, Zypher :D

Comment: ooh fail... I just tried it and powershell doesn't understand caps!? hrmm.